# Lua embedding in C++, how to handle uservalues

Tags: c++, lua

I am embedding Lua into a C++ application and would like to have a Lua table be associated with a C pointer.

In the object constructor I have:

```cpp
Thing (const std::string name_, lua_State * L): name(name_)
    {
        std::string filename = name + ".lua";

        luaL_dofile(L, filename.c_str());        

        lua_pushlightuserdata(L, this);
        
        lua_newtable(L);
        lua_setuservalue(L, 1); // Associate the Lua table with the userdata.

        luaL_getmetatable(L, "Metatable.Thing");

        lua_setmetatable(L, 1);

    }
```

In the __newindex metamethod of the "Metatable.Thing" metatable I have:

```cpp
static int ThingNewIndex(lua_State * L)
    {
        assert(lua_isuserdata(L, 1)); 
        assert(lua_isstring(L, 2));  

        Thing * thing = (Thing *)lua_touserdata(L, 1);
        const char * index = lua_tostring(L, 2);

        lua_getuservalue(L, 1);
       
        assert(lua_istable(L, -1)); // This assertion fails.

        lua_pushvalue(L, 2);
        lua_pushvalue(L, 3);
        lua_settable(L, -3);    

        return 0;
    
    }
```

The lua_getuservalue function does not put any table onto the stack.

Am I misunderstanding something about how user values work? Is there another way to associate a C++ pointer with a Lua table?

Comment: Lightuserdata is not userdata.  It can not have a uservalue.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you! Is there any way I can handle the memory allocation/dealocation from C++ but still have a uservalue?

Comment: Store "uservalue" in the registry.  Store registry index (int value) in your C++ object.